# Off-Topic Question: Direct Response To Answer In Separate Question

Tags: discussion, off-topic

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/682551/21700-lithium-ion-cell-battery-packs-commercial-off-the-shelf-direct-purchas) was closed as off-topic:

> Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them.

If veterans are recommending in their answers that battery units should be implemented in designs (rather than designed from a lower level), but good-faith searches for such a unit (at an approximate power level) turn up nothing, asking whether such a device actually exists (and not for the community to perform for a specific component downselect or provide retailer locations for a specific component) feels on-topic, as does asking (in the case of 'no') whether it is therefore safe and professionally advisable to forego the prior answer's advice and instead design a battery from scratch.

Since lithium ion safety circuitry questions are pretty hot right now, if the answer indeed is that uncertified battery manufacturers should not be designing batteries, and the site's users are generally doing so potentially because availability of such completed units are not apparent (with proof in the question that searching has been performed, in good-faith), then confirmation of their existence feels important.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is, don't ask for products to purchase in questions. If you want to ask a design question that is fine

Answer (score 4):

I'm impressed by the effort that you put into the original question. However, it seems to be "fairly ireedeemably" a shopping question. I raised this with the other moderators. I personally feel that questions like this are valuable to some BUT that still doesn't make them a good fit for the site. Sadly.

For an excellent  forum that supports discussion look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist, join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements as possible.

Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively). The site supports a conversational approach. Some SE members are also PICList members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Comment: Could I reask the question in brevity to remove the shopping aspect? `"I'm trying to implement a 3x2 21700 cell array. An answer recommended using a commercial off-the-shelf unit. Does such a thing exist?"` (This removes any design conversation surrounding safety concerns j: regarding the next-best alternatives, (some of which you were able to immediately point out), but it at least would cue in viewers whether a low-profile high-capacity 21700 cell-array **requires** a (risky) scratch design — an answer which continues to evade me, as my personal attempts put up clear flags for site regulars.

Comment: @kando -- that's still a shopping question.

Comment: Okay, thank you for confirming ☺️

Answer (score 0):

Such a question (with a simple yes/no answer) is a good fit for [the EE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=electronics.stackexchange.com) IMO.